# Best Way / data structure to count occurrences of strings

Tags: java, counting, find-occurrences, word-frequency

Lets assume I have a very long list of strings. I want to count the number of occurrences of each string. I don't know how many and of what kind the strings are (means: I have no dictionary of all possible strings)

My first idea was to create a Map and to increase the integer every time I find the key again.

But this feels a bit clumsy. Is there a better way to count all occurrences of those strings?

Comment: `"this feels a bit clumsy"`: how?

Comment: Clumsy or not it's the best possible approach for the problem. Depending on how would you like to read the set later on choose a proper map implementation. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 8, the easiest way is to use streams:

```
Map<String, Long> counts =
    list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Prior to Java 8, your currently outlined approach works just fine. (And the Java 8+ way is doing basically the same thing too, just with a more concise syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without streams too:

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

list.forEach(x -> map.merge(x, 1L, Long::sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a specific datastructure, you can always look towards [Guava's `Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html):

Usage will be similar to this:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("a b c a a".split(" "));

Multiset<String> wordCounts = words.stream()
  .collect(toCollection(HashMultiset::create));

wordCounts.count("a"); // returns 3
wordCounts.count("b"); // returns 1
wordCounts.count("z"); // returns 0, no need to handle null!
```